# VLOOKUP with dynamic column index number (ROW, ROWS, COUNTA)

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, row

This is the available data:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | traitA | traitB | traitC | traitD |
| item2 | traitE | traitF | traitG | traitH |
| item3 | traitI | traitJ | traitK |  |
| item4 | traitL | traitM | traitN |  |
| item5 | traitO | traitP |  |  |

I have a column of 5,000+ items. They all have different traits (some 2, some up to 20). Those traits are in the same row, in the columns next to the item. I already have the trait count per item and stacked the items for the right amount. Resulting in:

| Column Q | Column R |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | 4 |
| item2 | 4 |
| item3 | 3 |
| item4 | 3 |
| item5 | 2 |

and:

| Column Y | Column Z |
| --- | --- |
| item1 |  |
| item1 |  |
| item1 |  |
| item1 |  |
| item2 |  |
| item2 |  |
| item2 |  |
| item2 |  |
| item3 |  |
| item3 |  |
| item3 |  |
| item4 |  |
| item4 |  |
| item4 |  |
| item5 |  |
| item5 |  |

The result I need is the following:

| Column Y | Column Z |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | traitA |
| item1 | traitB |
| item1 | traitC |
| item1 | traitD |
| item2 | traitE |
| item2 | traitF |
| item2 | traitG |
| item2 | traitH |
| item3 | traitI |
| item3 | traitJ |
| item3 | traitK |
| item4 | traitL |
| item4 | traitM |
| item4 | traitN |
| item5 | traitO |
| item5 | traitP |

I put this in cell Z2:
=VLOOKUP(Y2,$A:$E,2,FALSE)
This works but only for traitA, traitE, traitI, and so on (column B).

So what I need is a dynamic column index number. This needs to find how many 'item1' there are in Column Y in total, and then at which one out of the total in column Y it is at.

Also when you go to the next item, the column index number has to go back to '2', since that will make the VLOOKUP work.

The column index numbers need to be as follows:

| Column Y | Column Z |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | 2 |
| item1 | 3 |
| item1 | 4 |
| item1 | 5 |
| item2 | 2 |
| item2 | 3 |
| item2 | 4 |
| item2 | 5 |
| item3 | 2 |
| item3 | 3 |
| item3 | 4 |
| item4 | 2 |
| item4 | 3 |
| item4 | 4 |
| item5 | 2 |
| item5 | 3 |

Don't have too much experience with ROW and ROWS, I cannot get it to work. Maybe VBA offers the best solution. Or does there also needs to be a COUNTA function?

Any help would be truly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What excel version do you have?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 365 Enterprise

Comment: I answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75160543/looking-for-vba-code-data-in-table-need-to-be-filter-and-then/75161274#75161274) yesterday. What you want to do is unpivot the first column. Can you check it you can follow the instructions and do it with a query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula - based on a table called `data`

```
=LET(traits,data[[Column B]:[Column E]],
items,MAP(traits,LAMBDA(i,INDEX(data[Column A],ROW(i)-1))),
FILTER(HSTACK(TOCOL(items),TOCOL(traits)),TOCOL(traits)<>0))
```

The basic idea is to use `TOCOL` - for the traits that's easy.

Regarding the items the trick is to fill the traits-matrix with the according item - and then do the `TOCOL`

(Important: you have to be on the *current channel* of Excel 365 to have `TOCOL` and `HSTACK`)

[image]